# Regular expression which allows alphabets, dashes(-) and dot(.)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to write a regex which allows alphabets, dot .  and dashes - (for validation)

But couldn't find a valid regex which would do so, please help!

Thanks in advance

Comment: You don't find regex, you build them. Show us what you have tried.

Comment: Can you give an example of text that is valid and some that isnt

Comment: I built this but it only allows alphabetical characters and spaces

^[a-zA-Z][\sa-zA-Z]*$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this will work for you

```
^[a-zA-Z-.]*$
```

any lowercase letter of the alphabet, any uppercase letter of the alphabet, dash as a group in any combination appearing 1 or many times

Answer (score 3):

This character class should work for you:

```
[a-zA-Z.-]
```

#### Must Read: http://regular-expressions.info

Answer (score 3):

Use this regex ([A-Za-z.-]) and test here http://www.rubular.com/r/H3Axvol13b

Answer (score 1):

```
(?i)[a-z.-]
```

(?i) Will find any character no matter what case